# UTF-8 Characters not Replacing

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

Yes, this is another encoding/decoding question. I am having trouble with replacing UTF-8 characters is this string:

```
data = json.dumps(JSON)
```

In this string I am trying to replace...

```
“
”
’
‘
"
```

...with " and ':

```
# replacing both types for good measure    
data = data.replace('“','"').replace('”','"').replace('’',"'").replace('‘',"'")
data = data.replace(u'\u201c','"').replace(u'\u201d','"').replace(u'\u2019',"'").replace(u'\u2018',"'")
```

However, this still returns the UTF-8 codes:

```
"\u201c\n\u201d\n\u2019\n\u2018\n"
```

What have I missed?

Comment: The JSON data contains a literal sequence `\u201c`, ie. six characters starting with a backslash. If you want to replace this, you need to type a Python string literal with two backslashes, ie. `"\\u201c"`. NOTE: if you insert ASCII double quotes after `json.dumps`, you're going to have invalid JSON. JSON strings cannot have unescaped double quotes.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful! I ended up managing to make it work by adding an `ensure_ascii=False` argument to the json.dumps() method.

Comment: This is good to hear, but you should be aware that you ended up doing something quite different from what you asked: you tried modifying the content (replacing `“` with `"`), but now you're changing the representation only.